# How to serve clojurescript over flask

Tags: python, flask, clojurescript

I have a small Flask app and I want to use some ClojureScript to enhance the user experience on the client-side.

Now I have trouble serving clojurescript via flask, as the paths get mixed up.

Flask asserts that static files like Javascript scripts lie in a directory `static`. I have changed my `project.clj` so that the compile target is put there:

```
                     :output-to  "static/plot.js"
                     :output-dir "static"
```

Unfortunately, when loading this file, it cannot load the dependent files with `goog.require`:

```
"ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?"
```

I believe that what is missing is a leading `/static` instead of `static` in the paths.

Can I specify a prefix with leiningen cljsbuild or clojurescript for those inlcudes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify an `:asset-path` in your compiled options (as the error message suggests). From https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#asset-path

> When using :main it is often necessary to control where the entry point script attempts to load scripts from due to the configuration of the web server. :asset-path is a relative URL path not a file system path.
>
> ```
>    :asset-path "assets/js"
> ```